# Why are India's sedition laws still on the books?

Tags: united-kingdom, law, india

Why India has not done away with archiac and abusive sedition laws once imposed by Colonial British rule?
It is not a political issue as all the major parties that have governed India since 1947 have not abolished it, neither any  opposition party has called for an abolition.

Countries like UK which had brought in the Sedition Law and USA are done away with this law, then how is that India is still using this law to punish it's citizens as late as 2021.

> **Sedition was Created to Prevent the Criticism of the King**
> Sedition was devised as a tool in 13th century Britain to suppress the freedom of the printing press and its ability to criticise the King. The Sedition Act, 1661 imposed punishment on anyone who wrote, printed or preached any words against the King. It evolved to mean slander and libel against the reputation or actions of government officials and judges. The goal was to protect the faith that the common person had in the government and to avoid a ‘breach of peace’ in society.

Comment: Just because something isn't an issue at the moment doesn't mean that laws about it should be removed. There are many examples around the world of old outdated laws staying on the books for no real reason. And as far as it being outdated there are people in the US who have recently been convicted of sedition. https://apnews.com/article/oath-keepers-seditious-conspiracy-conviction-2b9fb724c9839524d00ee389959e0e62

Comment: @JoeW I did read about that US Oath Keepers case, I don't know why they had to charged with sedition, but otherwise they could be charged with terrorist activities, storming a capitol.

Comment: Because these are convenient leftovers for countries whose governments don't mind little bit of authoritarianism "for a good cause".  Singapore had something similar that quasi-derived from the UK.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedition_Act_(Singapore)  Ditto Malaysia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedition_Act_1948  It takes a fair amount of guts and self-confidence for a government to ditch such self-serving laws or a very strong ability for public society to hold its government to account to get it repealed.

Comment: Because it wasn't just storming the capital and it involved an attempt to overturn the results of an election. You might not agree with it or understand why but what they got charged with and convicted of isn't as simple as a terrorist  attack of storming the capital.

Comment: **It is a political issue** in India. In the 2019 manifesto, one of India's oldest political party, [the Indian National Congress, promised to remove / dilute sedition laws and defamation laws](https://indianexpress.com/elections/congress-manifesto-2019-party-vows-to-scrap-sedition-law-criminal-defamation-5654640/) in its election manifesto. (And note that every country has its own version of "seditious" laws even if they don't call it that - why do you think the United States has rendition centres and foreign jails if not to jail and torture people it couldn't otherwise in the US itself?)

Comment: @sfxedit I think you're confusing two separate concepts there. Sedition is a regular (federal) crime that is charged, tried, and sentenced in the regular court system. As Joe W pointed out there are a number of rather prominent such trials at the moment. "Rendition" is for people we don't want to give charges, trials, or sentences, and indeed would prefer not to admit exist in the first place.

Comment: **And let's be careful when talking about sedition laws.**  If we're talking about having a law **against overthrowing the government** (ex Jan 6 @ Capitol) you can expect almost every country to have them.  If you are talking about a sedition law like [India's](https://www.hrw.org/news/2022/07/18/sedition-law-why-india-should-break-britains-abusive-legacy) : *making it a criminal offense to “bring, or attempt to bring, **into hatred or contempt, or excite disaffection towards, the Government**.”*  then that's quite a lot broader and a cause for concern.

Comment: @Cadence No, I am not confused. But you are technically right. I am looking at solely from the perspective of rights - both the sedition laws and "legal" renditions are designed to pulverise people's legal rights. (And I wasn't trying to indulge in whataboutism - sedition laws in India do need to go).

Comment: The trivial answer to the title question, of course, is because the laws were adopted at sometime in the past and no one has passed a law repealing them.

Comment: It takes work to repeal laws, and that effort can be more usefully spent doing other things. It's relatively easy for the government to tell the law enforcement personnel not to bother enforcing outdated laws.

Comment: @Barmar no because the laws stay on the books they can be abused by the ruling government, especially against the opposition.

Comment: @Up-In-Air True. And sometimes that's desired. Consider all the anti-abortion laws that were voided by Roe, but re-enabled by Dobbs. The Republicans are happy those laws stayed on the books.

Comment: @Barmar but I still feel the sedition laws which are technically based of *King Ruling* have been very stringent. We can create new laws for terrorist activities like India did for TADA and I forget the US laws created after 9/11 by homeland dept

Comment: @Up-In-Air Yeah, truly *bad* laws should be repealed. My comment was more about obsolete laws, like all the laws related to horses that are not relevant since cars took over.